# How to convert duration to seconds in Google Sheets which uses IMPORTRANGE

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-formula

I have copied the data from Googlesheet1 to Googlesheet2 using the below query

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:H")
```

Which has copied the data from Googlesheet1 to Googlesheet2.

In that sheet, I am having a duration column like the below image

[image]

When i used the app script to copy the data to the firestore instead of saving the duration it saves the data in DateTime format like below.
[image]

Is there any way to convert the given duration to seconds in Google sheet.

I have tried using `=value(G2*24*3600)` but it didn't work in the Googlesheet2 since that sheet is a clone of Googlesheet1

App script Logic:

```
function firestore() {
   // Firestore setup
   const email = "//client-email";
   const key = "//client-key";
   const projectId = "timesheet-aog";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);

   // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "timesheet";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

   console.log('sourceLen is', sourceLen);
   // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){

     var data = {};

     console.log('data is', sourceData);

     data.date = sourceData[i][0];
     data.name = sourceData[i][1];
     data.workFrom = sourceData[i][2];
     data.project = sourceData[i][3];
     data.phase = sourceData[i][4];
     data.task = sourceData[i][5];
     data.totalHrs = sourceData[i][6];
     data.comments = sourceData[i][7];

   firestore.createDocument("timesheet",data);

  }

}
```

Comment: Try putting this in cell `A1` in Googlesheet2 `={IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:G"), ARRAYFORMULA(N(IMPORTRANGE("url","!H2:H")) * 24 * 3600)})`(edit: added `ARRAYFORMULA`)

Comment: Sorry, mistaken one  column for another. Try this: `={IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:F"), ARRAYFORMULA(N(IMPORTRANGE("url","!G2:G")) * 24 * 3600), IMPORTRANGE("url","!H2:H")})`

Comment: @kishkin it returns as 0 in G column

Comment: Yes it does, but for empty cells and for 0 durations (which is ok I assume). What do you want for empty cells? Or do you get it for every cell, even with the non-zero value?

Comment: also I had a typo: no need for the last `)` right at the end

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @kishkin i tried but instead of the second's everything was 0's

Comment: Here is the version without trailing zeros: `={IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:F"), ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTRANGE("url","!G2:G") = "", "", N(IMPORTRANGE("url","!G2:G")) * 24 * 3600)), IMPORTRANGE("url","!H2:H")}`

Comment: Here's what i am getting https://imgur.com/a/WuqL9fa

Comment: You are importing a different sheet, aren't you? :) So, you should adjust for your columns. `={IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:D"), ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTRANGE("url","!E2:E") = "", "", N(IMPORTRANGE("url","!E2:E")) * 24 * 3600)), IMPORTRANGE("url","!F2:F")}`

Comment: Alternatively you can use named ranges in your original sheet, and import them by names in the second sheet, and you will not have to adjust.

Comment: But both have the same content and even i tried the sheet which i have shared to you still i am getting the same like the image https://imgur.com/xCXI9Yc

Comment: Not the same content: `1YwLY...` this one (the one you've shared has 2 more columns before duration.

Comment: @kishkin the new one works but why it differs based

Comment: @Nidhinkumar because you there are exact column names are used, exact column (`E:E` in the second case is Duration) is converted to seconds. If you convert another column (which is empty) you won't get anything.

Comment: @Nidhinkumar bro how did you upload the timestamp variable in firestore. When I do the same it returns an empty map object. Check this question out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the formula for `A1` cell of the second sheet:

```
={
  IMPORTRANGE("url","!A2:F"),
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      IMPORTRANGE("url","!G2:G") = "",
        "",
        N(IMPORTRANGE("url","!G2:G")) * 24 * 3600
    )
  ),
  IMPORTRANGE("url","!H2:H")
}
```

Try using named ranges for columns (`A2:F`, `G2:G`, `H2:H`) in the original sheet, and import them by those names so you won't need to adjust the formula where exact column names are used.